# Pop-up notification from carrier

Tags: notifications

What is this type of notification called and how can I block these?

[image: alt]

"MTS" is the name of the carrier. The messages are all ads. I've never seen one of these in the UK, but I receive one every 20 minutes in Ukraine. I've not installed anything recently, I only swapped SIM cards.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but they may be sending it via Cell Broadcast. To access the menu, head into Settings>Wireless & networks>Cell broadcasts and try turning it off. If it is already off, try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.denper.addonsdetector&hl=en addons manager app will tell you what has access to what and what can send you notifications. Failing that, come back here and we'll see what else can be done.

Comment: Also there is a setting in the SMS application called 'Push Messages' that are from the network. Disable this also.

Comment: How did you get on? Did it work?

Comment: what does the message say ?

Comment: Hello from 2018, did you find a solution yet? My carrier send offers and it is annoying, I disabled everything I can and the pop-up still showing up.

Answer (score 2):

I have since found that this is neither a push message nor a cell broadcast. I disabled both, yet still received these. One of the two was already disabled by default, can't remember which.

Apparently by inserting the SIM card, I got an "app" called "MTS Menu". This is the app that shows the messages. Using App Master, I found that this app comes from /system/app/Stk.apk:

[image]

"STK" appears to stand for [SIM Application Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_Application_Toolkit), basically a feature of SIM cards that enables operators to bundle "value added services", aka bundleware/crapware.

It is really stupid that Android comes not only with this feature enabled, but also makes the source of these pop-ups very difficult to trace.

Comment: very interesting finding, mine has it not, there may be some other app that does the same; now I have to track mine down.. thx!

Comment: How did you trace it?

Comment: How to uninstall it? The system doesn't show the uninstall option. Stopping the service doesn't work either, it keeps on popping up

Comment: How the hell would you trace it?? Why is no one replying? :(